# Python - Local csv file isn't being properly sent to slack channel via SlackAPI

Tags: python, python-2.7, slack-api

I am trying to send a local `csv` file to a slack channel that I created with a  `Python` script via the `SlackAPI`. My script executes, but the file is being sent as a private file only visible to me. I would like it to be visible in the entire channel and look something like this:

[image: Desired Output]

I have seen other questions similar to this that were posted, but I still can't seem to get this code to do what I have described. I am the owner of the channel and I am using a legacy token. Below is my code:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient

sc = SlackClient('Token')

sc.api_call(
"files.upload",
filename='sample.csv',
channel='#secdevtest1',
username='AMI Rehydrator',
file=open('sample.csv', 'r').read()
)
```

Comment: You want to upload the entire file AND a snippet from the file?

Comment: No, just the entire file. I think that is just Slack's default behavior for previewing the file. But, I could be wrong.

Comment: Try replacing `channel` with `channels`.

Comment: @huck_cussler aahhh.. Seconds away...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `channels` instead of `channel`

Furthermore, from [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload)

> By default all newly-uploaded files are private and only visible to
>   the owner. They become public once they are shared into a public
>   channel (which can happen at upload time via the `channels` argument).

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Comment: @dmn0972 good! Those typos can drive a man (or woman) insane ;) I just added some info for other users aswell

Comment: Reading documentation also helps.. ;)